# Auto Refresh a DIV every 5 Seconds code Not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Friends

I have the following code to refresh the following DIV id refreshDiv to auto refresh every 5 seconds but it is not working

```
<div id ="refreshDiv" class="span2" style="text-align:left;">
  <c:set var="map" value="${alertStatusForm.channelStateForRecipients[currentChannel]}"></c:set>
<div>
<label><img src="${channelIcon}">&nbsp;
  ${fn:length(map['DELIVERED'])}</label>
 </div>
 <div>
 <label><img src="${channelIcon}">&nbsp;
  ${fn:length(map['FAILED'])}</label>
 </div>
 <div>
<label><img src="${channelIcon}">&nbsp;
${fn:length(map['IN_PROGRESS'])}</label>
</div>
</div>

function refreshDiv(){
     $.ajax({
        url: 'editReg.jsp'
    }).done(function(result) {
        $('#refreshDIV').text(result);
    });
}
```

Comment: dont u need `setInterval` for this?

Comment: nobody is invoking the function `refreshDIV`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not calling `refreshDiv()`. You just defined it. Call this function when dom is loaded and keep calling after each 5 seconds using `setTimeout`.

```
$(function(){
    function refreshDiv(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'editReg.jsp'
        }).done(function(result) {
            $('#refreshDIV').text(result);
            window.setTimeout(refreshDiv, 5000);
        });

    }
    window.setTimeout(refreshDiv, 5000);
});
```